# How do I pass a string from a c# app to class ctor in a c++ cli dll?

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

I have a VS2013 solution with 2 projects. One is a c++/cli dll. The other is a c# console app. The dll contains a class whose ctor takes a `const WCHAR *` parameter. In the C# app, I tried to create an instance of the class. I used a string literal for the ctor parameter. The build error is:

The best overloaded method match for `MyLib.MyClass.Myclass(char*)` has some invalid arguments

I have 2 questions.

1. Why does VS2013 think the parameter is `char*` instead of `WCHAR*`?
2. How can I pass a string from c# to C++?

The purpose of this work is to see if using a C++/cli dll is easier than just using dllimport/pinvoke.

Comment: You should use `System::String^` in your C++/CLI code for .Net strings. If you then need to send to C or native C++ code, use `marshal_as`.

Comment: Char in C# is WCHAR in C++. In your managed class you SHOULD use only managed types, at least in its public interface

Comment: If you're not going to do it the easy way with `System::String ^`, will the class expect the pointer to be valid after the ctor returns?